# Summernote editor and script tags

Tags: javascript, summernote

I am building a web app which uses [Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) to allow for HTML editing.

Users are allowed to add and edit JavaScript as well, using inline `<script>` tags. This works fine and can be done in the editor's "Code View" mode.

What I'd like to do is, in the preview/WYSIWYG mode, instead of having the script being executed, just display an image (or text) to let the user know that there's a script there.

Something like:

[image: Summernote in Code View mode]
[image: Summernote in normal/WYSIWYG mode showing JavaScript as an icon]

I looked around and I don't think this has been done before. Is it possible? Any pointers on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/495 explains how to do it using CSS only.

Comment: Yep. pingram3541 answered my question there. I still haven't tried it though.